# Laravel: how can i get files from database in edit form. so i dont have to reupload if i dont want to change the files

Tags: laravel

blade edit

```
<form action="/files" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <label for="dokumen">Dokumen Awal : ({{$aktivitas_list->dokumen}}) <br><i>Upload Ulang Dokumen</i></label>
   <input type="file" id="dokumen" name="dokumen"  accept=".pdf" class="form-control" value="{{$aktivitas_list->dokumen}}">             
   @if ($errors->has('dokumen'))
      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('dokumen') }}</span>
   @endif
```

controller store

```
$aktivitas_list = new Aktivitas;
$aktivitas_list->pt_id = $request->get('pt_id');
$aktivitas_list->nama_aktivitas = $request->get('nama_aktivitas');
$aktivitas_list->tgl_aktivitas = $request->get('tgl_aktivitas');
$aktivitas_list->tempat = $request->get('tempat');
$aktivitas_list->jenis_aktivitas = $request->get('jenis_aktivitas');
$aktivitas_list->dokumen = $request->file('dokumen');
$aktivitas_list->tenggat_waktu = $request->get('tenggat_waktu');
$aktivitas_list->deskripsi = $request->get('deskripsi');
$aktivitas_list->status = $request->get('status');
$aktivitas_list->user = $request->get('user');
            
    
$rules = array(
    'nama_aktivitas' => 'required',
    'dokumen' => 'required|mimes:pdf'
);
    
$dokumen = $request->file('dokumen');
$tujuan_upload = 'document-upload';
$dokumen->move($tujuan_upload, $dokumen->getClientOriginalName());
$aktivitas_list->dokumen = $dokumen->getClientOriginalName();
     
    if ($aktivitas_list->save()) {
       return redirect('pt')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
    } else {
        return redirect('pt')->with('error', 'error message');
    }
}
```

controller update

```
$rules = array(
      'nama_aktivitas' => 'required',
      'dokumen' => 'required|mimes:pdf'
);

  $dokumen = $request->file('dokumen');
  $tujuan_upload = 'document-upload';
  $dokumen->move($tujuan_upload, $dokumen->getClientOriginalName());
  $aktivitas_list->dokumen = $dokumen->getClientOriginalName();
  $aktivitas_list->status = $status=1;
  $aktivitas_list->user = Auth::user()->name;
  $user = Auth::user()->name;
      

  if ($aktivitas_list->save()) {
      return redirect('pt')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
  } else {
      return redirect('pt')->with('error', 'error message');
  }

The problem is, if I don't select again the file when I update the data so the data is null. for example i just want to edit field nama aktivitas and not change the files. and another example i want to update all field. how can i get the files beside the browse button? how can i solve them? please guys help me
```

Comment: Normally while updating you may not require the file to be uploaded every time. So first you can change the validation rule 'dokumen' => 'sometimes|mimes:pdf'. Then you can have a conditional check if($request->hasFile('dokumen'){ //code to store the file}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller on update method

1. Make file as optional.
2. Check if request has file then make process of upload.
3. in view you can't set file input value for security reason.

```php
$rules = array(
        'nama_aktivitas' => 'required',
        'dokumen' => 'nullable|mimes:pdf'//make file as optional
        );
    if($request->file('dokumen')){//check if file are exists on request
         $dokumen = $request->file('dokumen');
         $tujuan_upload = 'document-upload';
         $dokumen->move($tujuan_upload, $dokumen->getClientOriginalName());
         $aktivitas_list->dokumen = $dokumen->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $aktivitas_list->status = $status=1;
    $aktivitas_list->user = Auth::user()->name;
    $user = Auth::user()->name;
  

    if ($aktivitas_list->save()) {
        return redirect('pt')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
    } else {
        return redirect('pt')->with('error', 'error message');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if file existed then upload it and save file's new name in database and if file didn't exist just escape this field so old value remain in database.

```
if($request->hasFile()) {
    }
```

See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'nama_aktivitas' => 'required',
        'dokumen' => 'sometimes|mimes:pdf'
     );
    
     //Validation of request data

    if($request->hasFile('dokumen') && $request->file('dokumen')->isValid()){
        
        $dokumen = $request->file('dokumen');
        $tujuan_upload = 'document-upload';
        $dokumen->move($tujuan_upload, $dokumen->getClientOriginalName());

        //Since your provided code snippet for update is truncated
        // don't know how $aktivitas_list is instantiated
        $aktivitas_list->dokumen = $dokumen->getClientOriginalName();
    }
     
    $aktivitas_list->status = $status=1;
    $aktivitas_list->user = Auth::user()->name;
    $user = Auth::user()->name;

  

    if ($aktivitas_list->save()) {
        return redirect('pt')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
    } else {
        return redirect('pt')->with('error', 'error message');
    }
}
```